# SpringBoot unit test using JPA and JOOQ

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, jpa, jooq

I had to start with the following codebase: an ordinary `JpaRepository` that also implemented more complex custom JPQL queries defined inside `TokenOrderRepositoryCustom`

```
public interface TokenOrderRepository<T extends TokenOrderEntity> extends
       JpaRepository<T, Long>, 
       TokenOrderRepositoryCustom {
}
```

This was unit tested using the following configuration:

```
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase (replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
public class TokenOrderRepositoryTest {
}
```

Now, I had to add a complex query in `TokenOrderRepository` that uses window functions and I've settled to use `JOOQ` for that. In order to do that I had to use JOOQ's `DSLContext` in  `TokenOrderRepositoryCustomImpl`

```
public class TokenOrderRepositoryCustomImpl implements TokenOrderRepositoryCustom {
    @Autowired
    private DSLContext jooqContext;
}
```

The problem is that now I have a mixed repository that uses both JPA and JOOQ and I cannot figure how to modify the configuration for `TokenOrderRepositoryTest` to accommodate that.

Your guidance would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I finally got around this problem by importing the configuration defining the `DSLContext` for the JPA tests. I don't know if it is the perfect approach, but it works effortlessly.

```
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase (replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
@Import(value = JOOQConfiguration.class)
public class TokenOrderRepositoryTest {
}
```